# SyntaxError: invalid syntax when installing graphite

Tags: django, graphite

I installed the following:
Graphite,Carbon,Whisper : 0.9.15，Django: 1.5，Python：2.6.6 under the Centos 6.7.
After started Httpd successfully, the same error occured in the file: error.log.
why and how to fixed it, I appreciate your help.

Thanks.

```
[Tue Sep 27 16:08:38 2016] [error] warn('SECRET_KEY is set to an unsafe default. This should be set in local_settings.py for better security')

[Tue Sep 27 16:08:38 2016] [error] [client ::1] mod_wsgi (pid=2761): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/opt/graphite/conf/graphite.wsgi'.

[Tue Sep 27 16:08:38 2016] [error] [client ::1] Traceback (most recent call last):

[Tue Sep 27 16:08:38 2016] [error] [client ::1] File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 255, in call
[Tue Sep 27 16:08:38 2016] [error] [client ::1] response = self.get_response(request)

[Tue Sep 27 16:08:38 2016] [error] [client ::1] File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 178, in get_response

[Tue Sep 27 16:08:38 2016] [error] [client ::1] response = self.handle_uncaught_exception(request, resolver, sys.exc_info())

[Tue Sep 27 16:08:38 2016] [error] [client ::1] File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 220, in handle_uncaught_exception

[Tue Sep 27 16:08:38 2016] [error] [client ::1] if resolver.urlconf_module is None:

[Tue Sep 27 16:08:38 2016] [error] [client ::1] File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 342, in urlconf_module

[Tue Sep 27 16:08:38 2016] [error] [client ::1] self.urlconf_module = import_module(self.urlconf_name)

[Tue Sep 27 16:08:38 2016] [error] [client ::1] File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module

[Tue Sep 27 16:08:38 2016] [error] [client ::1] __import_(name)

[Tue Sep 27 16:08:38 2016] [error] [client ::1] File "/opt/graphite/webapp/graphite/urls.py", line 32, in 

[Tue Sep 27 16:08:38 2016] [error] client ::1,

[Tue Sep 27 16:08:38 2016] [error] [client ::1] File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/conf/urls/init.py", line 25, in include

[Tue Sep 27 16:08:38 2016] [error] [client ::1] urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)

[Tue Sep 27 16:08:38 2016] [error] [client ::1] File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module

[Tue Sep 27 16:08:38 2016] [error] [client ::1] import(name)

[Tue Sep 27 16:08:38 2016] [error] [client ::1] File "/opt/graphite/webapp/graphite/render/urls.py", line 16, in 

[Tue Sep 27 16:08:38 2016] [error] [client ::1] from . import views

[Tue Sep 27 16:08:38 2016] [error] [client ::1] File "/opt/graphite/webapp/graphite/render/views.py", line 32, in 

[Tue Sep 27 16:08:38 2016] [error] [client ::1] from graphite.remote_storage import connector_class_selector

[Tue Sep 27 16:08:38 2016] [error] [client ::1] File "/opt/graphite/webapp/graphite/remote_storage.py", line 168

[Tue Sep 27 16:08:38 2016] [error] [client ::1] for series in unpickle.loads(pickled_response)

[Tue Sep 27 16:08:38 2016] [error] [client ::1] ^

[Tue Sep 27 16:08:38 2016] [error] [client ::1] SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 0):

As deciphered from traceback goto line no. 168 of file /opt/graphite/webapp/graphite/remote_storage.py

Then add a colon **:** at the end of for loop. It should resolve your problem. Though this is a quickfix but I would recommend that after this attempt is succesful try reinstalling graphite, because on [github the file has different code on this line](https://github.com/tmm1/graphite/blob/master/webapp/graphite/remote_storage.py#L168).